# Why is Eclipse Juno running very slow?

Tags: android, eclipse

Hey guys I am developing Android apps on eclipse and its running very slow. So slow that I am not able to program properly because of this thing.

E.g - when I click on Graphical layout in xml it takes around 10 secs to shift from graphical to xml code. The same is happening in java code too.

I am running Intel Core 2 Duo 1.83 GHz with 3gb RAM. Also I have provided 3gb as swap drive (logical not primary)

Comment: Can you edit your post to include system specs? How fast a machine do you have, how much RAM, etc? Last time I tried this a 2007 Core 2 Duo with 4 GB RAM was indeed too slow on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: Its really too slow please someone help me out soon else I will have to boot into windows for this which I really dont want to becoz I really love linux.

Comment: Can anyone help me out?

Comment: While I hadn't used Eclipse for Android dev (or more than 10 mins of java ... I'm more of a python person) it can sometimes be slow. When that happens I just delete all the trash that it creates in the ~/workspace/.metadata (as a matter of fact I delete the whole .metadata dir). It usually helps in my case.